# Reference model properties inside {{#view}} within {{#each}} block

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to reference a model property inside a handlebars `{{#view}}` which is itself inside a handlebars `{{#each}}` block. In the example below, the `{{title}}` property (inside the `<a>` tags) is output correctly, but the item property of the view ends up just being the string, 'title'.

```
  {{#each}}
    {{#view view.PostNavItemView item=title}}<a href="#" {{action goToRoute 'post' this}}>{{title}}</a>{{/view}}
  {{/each}}
```

Can I pass the `{{#each}}` model's properties into the view helper, somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `item` you should use `itemBinding`.

```
{{#view view.PostNavItemView itemBinding='title'}}
```